# Output to magit-process

Tags: magit, shell, shell-command

When I run built-in magit commands, they output to the magit-process buffer. How can I do the same with a custom magit command that generates shell output?

Answer (score 6):

You can run one-off commands using the `magit-run-popup` bound to `!`.
For example, `!!ls-files` will run `git ls-files` in the top-level
directory of the repo and output the results to the Magit process
buffer for that repo.

For writing your own commands, you can use one of
[Magit's functions for calling Git](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Calling-Git.html#Calling-Git),
picking the variant depending on the type of Git command and whether
you are calling it for a return value or for a side-effect.  The `!!`
command from above ends up calling `(magit-run-git-async "ls-files")` in the top-level directory of the repo.